# Convert vertical rectangles separated by `\n` to horizontal

Tags: bash, awk, transpose

I have a text file with values like this:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h

i j
k l
m n
o p

q r
s t
u v
w x
```

I want to convert vertical lines separated by `\n` to horizontal ones like this:

```
a c e g
b d f h

i k m o
j l n p

q s u w
r t v x
```

I have tried this:

```
WRD=$(head -n 1 a.txt | wc -w);
for((i=1; i<=$WRD; i++)); do
    awk '{print $'$i'}' a.txt | tr '\n' ' '; echo;
done > "sa.txt"
```

But the ouput looks like this:

```
a c e g  i k m o  q s u w 
b d f h  j l n p  r t v x
```

How can I edit it to output as I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash:

```
while read -r line1; do if [[ -z $line1 ]]; then echo; continue; fi; read -r line2; echo "$line1 $line2"; done < file
```

and with indent:

```
while read -r line1; do
  if [[ -z $line1 ]]; then
    echo
    continue
  fi
  read -r line2
  echo "$line1 $line2"
done < file
```

Output:

```
a b c d
e f g h

i j k l
m n o p

q r s t
u v w x
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the expected output, it's just combining pairs of lines rather than transposing lines.

Comment: .... and yet the OP has accepted this answer instead of one that does produce the expected output so I guess the posted question has little to do with what the OP actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS= '{
    for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        for (j=i;j<=NF;j+=2) {
            printf "%s%s", $j, (j<(NF+i-2)?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
a c e g
b d f h

i k m o
j l n p

q s u w
r t v x
```

Comment: This is more general  than other `awk` answers since it handles rectangles of varying sizes, and is cleaner than [my own tool-based general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623241/6136214).

Answer (score 2):

Try: This solution will also work for more than 2 fields, (the only thing I am considering here is you don't have any null fields).

```
awk '/^$/{for(j=1;j<=val;j++){print A[j];delete A[j];};print}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){;A[i]=A[i]?A[i] FS $i:$i};val=NF} END{for(j in A){print A[j]}}'   Input_file
```

The above one liner with explanation:

```
awk '/^$/{                                ####Checking for a condition where a line is NULL, if yes then perform following.
                for(j=1;j<=val;j++){      ####starting a for loop from variable i value from 1 to till variable val value.
                print A[j];               ####printing array A value with index j.
                delete A[j];              ####deleting array A value with index j.
                                   };
                print                     ####Print the NULL value which is new line.
         }
         {
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){;      ####Starting a loop from i value from 1 to till NF value, where NF is number of fields in a line.
                A[i]=A[i]?A[i] FS $i:$i   ####creating an array A whose index will be number of fields and it will concatenate in its own value.
                                  };
                val=NF                    ####creating a variable named val whose value is equal to NF value.
         }
    END  {                                ####Starting END section here too.
                for(j in A){              ####Starting a loop here which will loop through the array A.
                print A[j]                ####Printing the array A value with index j.
                           }
         }
   ' Input_file                           ####Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your data will become more complicated, but this should get you started:

```
awk 'NF{col1 = col1 (col1?FS:"") $1;col2 = col2 (col2?FS:"") $2;next}{print col1 RS col2;col1=col2=""}END{print col1 RS col2}' input_file
```

We use NF to let us know the lines that contain data and store them accordingly.

The END is required as there is not additional line after the last entries.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `sed` and `paste`:

   ```
   sed '/^$/p' inputfile | paste -d ' ' - -
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   a b c d
   e f g h

   i j k l
   m n o p

   q r s t
   u v w x
   ```

   ---

   Note that the above might not be up to spec, since it only works if
   the rectangles have even numbered *2x**n*** sides, (i.e. *2x4*
   transposed to *4x2*).  OTOH both [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622520/6136214)' and [grail's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621025/6136214)
   answers also fail on irregular rectangles, i.e. if fed `grep -v '[gx]' inputfile`.
2. A more general fix, (works on rectangles of any and varying sizes), using `csplit` and [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

   ```
   # Create a more irregular input file:
   grep -v '[gx]' inputfile | tee vlines3
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   a b
   c d
   e f

   i j
   k l
   m n
   o p

   q r
   s t
   u v
   ```

   Code:

   ```
   x=`mktemp -u`
   csplit -f $x --suppress-matched -s vlines3 '/^$/' '{*}'
   for f in ${x}* ; do 
        datamash -W -t' ' transpose < $f
        echo
        rm $f
   done | head -n  -1
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   a c e
   b d f

   i k m o
   j l n p

   q s u
   r t v
   ```